# Trigger Twilio Flow form Freshdesk Automation webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks, freshdesk

I need to trigger Twilio Flow Rest API via a webhook that freshdesk have on the automation feature.

[Twilio Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZdXv.png)

I configure the automation with webhook service: https://webhook.site and i received the data.

[Freshdesk Automation Webhook configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxhX5.png)

When I use POSTMAN to trigger the flow it works perfectly.

[POSTMAN TWILIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QxaQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, you are sending the data differently to Twilio with each approach.

The Freshdesk example is sending application/json but Postman (which you indicated works) is using form-data.Try selecting X-FORM-URLENCODED on the Freshdesk side.

[Creating or Updating Resources with the HTTP POST and PUT Methods](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio#post)

"Creating or updating a resource involves performing an HTTP PUT or HTTP POST to a resource URI. In the PUT or POST, you represent the properties of the object you wish to update as form urlencoded key/value pairs. Don't worry, this is already the way browsers encode POSTs by default. But be sure to set the HTTP Content-Type header to "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" for your requests if you are writing your own client."

Comment: I does not let me choose advance when selecting x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: You will have to contact Freshdesk, clearly they need a way to submit the form URL encoded values if they provide you that option.